# Polynom Space, check if U a base

Tags: linear-algebra

$R_5[x]$ is a polynom space which is lower than 5 over R (Including the zero polynom).

Given: $U = \{p(x) \in R_5[x] | p(0) = p(1) = p(2)\}$

1. Prove that U is a sub-space of $R_5[x]$. Find a base to U. and $dimU$.

Well, I started by taking a $p(x) \in R_5[x]$ which means taking a vector in $R_5[x]$

So,$ p(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e $,Because $p(0) = p(1) = p(2)$, I can say that:

$ p(0) = p(1), p(0) = p(2)$.
Which gives me 2 homo equations:

$a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 = 0$

$a16 + b8 + c4 + d2 = 0$

I put those $\{(1,1,1,1), (16,8,4,2)\}$ into a matrix and after elementary row operations I get to : $\{(1,0,-0.5,3/4) , (0,1,3/2,7/4)\}$

So I can say that:

$a = 0.5c + 3/4d$

$b = -2/3c - 7/4d$

Thus:

$p(x) = (0.5c + 3/4d)x^4 + (-3/2c - 7/4d)x^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$
$p(x) = (0.5x^4-3/2x^3+x^2)c+ (3/4x^4-7/4x^3+x)d + e$

So $U = Sp\{0.5x^4-3/2x^3+x^2, 3/4x^4-7/4x^3+x ,1\}$
Also, I can multiply the first vector by 2, the second vector by 4, to make the span easier to read:
So $u= Sp\{x^4-3x^3+2x^2, 3x^4-7x^3+4x ,1\}$

The question is: How can I check now that U is linearly independent so I can prove U is a base?
I thought that I could add 2 coordinate vectors (e3,e4) , which will get me a matrix 5x5 and I can then easily see that U is linearly independent. and thus, U is a base.
Then I say that DimU=3, and obviously U's base is $\{x^4-3x^3+2x^2, 3x^4-7x^3+4x ,1\}$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

For $p(x)\in U$, you can write $$p(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(ax+b)+c$$ for some reals $a,b,c$. Since there are three independent numbers having to be chosen then $\dim U=3$ and you can easily find the basis by putting $(a,b,c)$ with $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ that will give you 
$$\{x^2(x-1)(x-2),x(x-1)(x-2),1\}.$$

Comment: And about my question, Do I need to add 2 more vectors to check independence or just put ${x4−3x3+2x2,3x4−7x3+4x,1}$ in a matrix without adding 2 vectors to it and check its independence?

Comment: No. You only need to check your set is linearly independent. It can be done using definition or [Wronskian test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).